# Input of 3D array into Sequential model Keras (Python)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have a training input in 3 dimensions (8,50,3).
I am trying to pass it as an input to the Sequential Model in Keras. Looking up the documentation I found that this should work:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,3)))
model.add(Dense(100,init="uniform", activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(50,init="uniform", activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I try to train this model:

```
model.fit(train,labelTrain,epochs=1,batch_size=1,verbose=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error when checking model target: expected dense_148 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 1)
```

What can it mean?

Also, my first objective was to pass a 3D array where the middle dimension did not have a fixed size but I gave up after finding it impossible. Could it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Target` means it's the expected result. The problem is in `labelTrain`, not in the input.

A `Dense` layer must have a number of neurons. You don't pass it an output shape, you pass the amount of neurons, and the output is automatically (None, neurons)

Your last layer should be:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='I recomend an activation here'))
```